# Nested beans with StaticTableSchema & enhanced DynamoDB client from AWS Java SDK 2.x

Tags: amazon-web-services, kotlin, amazon-dynamodb, aws-java-sdk-2.x

How do I create a [`StaticTableSchema`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/enhanced/dynamodb/mapper/StaticTableSchema.html) for a nested bean (like for the `items` property here)?

```kotlin
data class Order(
    var id: Long = 0L,
    var items: List<OrderLineItem> = emptyList(),
    …
)
```

```kotlin
data class OrderLineItem(
    var id: Long = 0L,
    var price: BigDecimal = 0.0.toBigDecimal(),
    …
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, create a `TableSchema` implementation for the nested bean. It could be a [`StaticTableSchema`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/enhanced/dynamodb/mapper/StaticTableSchema.html) or a [`BeanTableSchema`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/enhanced/dynamodb/mapper/BeanTableSchema.html):

```kotlin
val orderLineItemStaticTableSchema = TableSchema
    .builder(OrderLineItem::class.java)
    .newItemSupplier(::OrderLineItem)
    .addAttribute(Long::class.java) {
        it.name("id").getter(OrderLineItem::id::get).setter(OrderLineItem::id::set)
    }
    .addAttribute(BigDecimal::class.java) {
        it.name("price").getter(OrderLineItem::price::get).setter(OrderLineItem::price::set)
    }
    .build()

// or

val orderLineItemBeanTableSchema = TableSchema.fromBean(OrderLineItem::class.java)
```

Then, use this schema instance with [`EnhancedType.documentOf()`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/enhanced/dynamodb/EnhancedType.html#documentOf-java.lang.Class-software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.TableSchema-):

```kotlin
val tableSchema = TableSchema
    .builder(Order::class.java)
    .newItemSupplier(::Order)
    .addAttribute(Long::class.java) {
        it.name("id").getter(Order::id::get).setter(Order::id::set)
    }
    .addAttribute(
        EnhancedType.listOf(
            EnhancedType.documentOf(OrderLineItem::class.java, orderLineItemTableSchema)
        )
    ) {
        it.name("items").getter(Order::items::get).setter(Order::items::set)
    }
    .build()
```